# Receving FFT data over a socket in Java

Tags: java, c, applet, fft, serversocket

I am trying to write an Applet that established a socket connection with a server and receives FFT data from that server, computes a spectrogram and displays it. Currently, this is what I have in C.

```
int getData(){
int i;
int constant;

// get as many bytes in the socket to fill up the buffer
n = recv(sockfd, tempBuf + readCount, length - readCount, MSG_DONTWAIT);    
if(n>0)
    readCount += n;

if(readCount == length) //when get enough data
{
    // check header constant 
    constant = ((int*)(tempBuf))[0];
    fprintf(stderr, "\nReading header... ");  
    printf("header.constSync is %X\n", constant);
    if(constant != 0xACFDFFBC)
        error1("ERROR reading from socket, incorrect header placement\n");

    //put data into a buffer
    for( i = 0 ; i < samp_rate; i++)
        buffer[i] = ((double*)(tempBuf + sizeof(struct fft_header)))[i];
    fprintf(stderr, "Reading data... ");

    //shift
    shift();
    readCount = 0;
}
return 1;
```

}

However I also wrote a similar method in Java that I am hoping will accomplish the same thing. Is this right?

```
    public int getData() throws IOException {  
    int constant;
    BufferedInputStream data = null;  
    try{
        data=new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 

    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        System.err.println("Invalid Host");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Couldn't get the I/O for the connection to the host");
    }

    int numBytes = data.available();
    if(numBytes >0){
        readCount+=numBytes;
    }
    if(readCount == length){
        constant = tempBuff[0];
        System.out.println("Reading Header");
        System.out.println(constant);
        if(constant != 0xACFDFFBC){
            System.err.println("Error reading from Socket. Incorrect Header Placement");                                
        }
        for(int i=0; i<samp_rate; i++){
            buffer[i] = tempBuff[i];
            System.out.println("Reading data...");
        }
    }               
    return 1;
```

}

**Edit - Sorry I forgot to post the actual question. What I am trying to ask is am I using bufferedInputStream correctly? Or should I use DataInputStream? Also I understand that available() is used to determine how many bytes to read. Am I using it right?

Comment: OK, so what is your question/problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should know perfectly well that it doesn't work, unless you haven't even bothered to try it, in which case you have no business to be posting here at all yet. There is:

- a misuse of `available()`
- an assignment to `constant` from an undeclared array variable that could be anything
- no actual reading going on at all.

You should be using the facilities of `DataInputStream` for this: `readInt(),` `readDouble(),` `readFully(),` etc. Wrap the `BufferedInputStream` in a `DataInputStream` and start calling those methods.

Comment: Using `DataInputStream` is the right way to do. It can be obtained directly by using `new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` without using `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: @tonga Of course it can, but it's miles less efficient that way.

Comment: Can you explain how its more or less efficient? And by wrapping do you mean:

new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());